# Manipulando retorno de função Async/Await com JSON.parse - REACTJS

Tags: json, react, typescript, async, async-await

Tenho o código abaixo que esta retornando um erro onde não estou compreendendo como solucionar. O console log de "ret.value" retorna {"id":1,"name":"Max"} em string corretamente, porem no JSON.parse.

```
Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

/

```
  async getObject() {
   const ret = await Storage.get({ key: 'user' });
   console.log(JSON.parse(ret.value)); // ERRO AQUI
   console.log(JSON.parse('{"id":1,"name":"Max"}')); // SEM ERRO TUDO RETORNA NORMAL
 }
```

Estou utilizando o Ionic com ReactJS, em TypeScript.

Creio que deva ser algo simples, porem tentei diversos exemplos e procurei aqui, porem nada solucionou o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está acontecendo porque o tipo do seu `ret.value` é uma união entre `string` e `null`.

Mesmo que no seu teste ele seja uma `string`, a declaração desse tipo contempla a possibilidade dele ser `null` também, e o tipo `null` não é uma parâmetro válido para o método `JSON.parse`, portanto o compilador não está aceitando o mesmo.

Para passar o parâmetro para o método `JSON.parse`, você pode utilizar um dos muitos *shields* do TypeScript. Se você adicionar um `if` para se certificar que `ret.value` é do tipo `string` dentro de determinado escopo, isso já será o suficiente para o compilador se certificar que ele é válido:

```
async getObject() {
    const ret = await Storage.get({ key: 'user' });
    if (typeof ret.value === 'string') {
        // dentro desse escopo você pode utilizar ret.value como se ele sempre fosse uma string
        console.log(JSON.parse(ret.value));
    }
}
```

Outra abordagem que você pode utilizar é criar uma variável que é do tipo `string`, e exclusivamente `string`:

```
async getObject() {
    const ret = await Storage.get({ key: 'user' });
    const value = ret.value ?? '';
    console.log(JSON.parse(value));
}
```

No exemplo acima, se `ret.value` for `null` o operador coalesce (`??`) irá resultar na string vazia, portanto o tipo de `value` não tem como ser `null`, logo é um parâmetro válido para `JSON.parse`

Comment: Muito obrigado :) Funcionou perfeitamente.